# Passing nid into a context view

Tags: views, 6

I have a context that is fired when it is on a node page. I wish to pass the nid of the node being viewed, into a view to display on the page. Is this possible? How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node id can be accessed by `arg(2)` function call on node page view. It would even work if you have defined a url alias using path/auto_path modules.

On the view, where you manage argument options, Try with `Provide default argument option` as `Node ID from URL`